# Cannot use cout with MPI

Tags: c++, mpi

I've tried to run a very basic program with MPI. There is an error while creating the object files using mpicc whenever I use a cout statement. However, if I replace this with a printf statement, everything works perfectly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  // Initialize the MPI environment.
  MPI_Init(NULL,NULL);

  // Get the number of processes
  int world_size;
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

  // Get the rank of the process
  int world_rank;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

  // Get the name of the processor
  char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
  int name_len;
  MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &name_len);

  // Print off a hello world message
  //printf("Processor %s, rank %d out of %d processors\n",
  //       processor_name, world_rank, world_size);
  std::cout<<"Processor "<< processor_name<<" , rank "<<world_rank<<" out of  processors "<<world_size<<std::endl;        

  // Finalize the MPI environment. No more MPI calls can be made after this
  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Has anyone faced this problem before?

Comment: I don't want to unpack zips just for having a first look at your code. Post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: What is the error and can you at least post the offending line of code?

Comment: mpicc is, btw, likely the c-, not the c++-wrapper of your mpi installation.

Answer (score 3):

As a I already indicated in the comment, use mpic++ (or however the C++ wrapper is called on your platform), not mpicc.

---

With my local mpic++.mpich2, the code in the Q compiles and links.

---

The problem with mpicc is that in the linker stage, it does not automatically link with libstdc++, libc++ or whatever C++ std lib you have on your platform, thus the linker cannot resolve std::cout and other symbols.

Comment: Using mpic++ worked for me. I had been able to resolve the problem with mpicc as well but needed to explicitly mention the libc++ library while linking.

Answer (score 1):

Addition to bottom the answer.Or if you are working in Windows, use VS 2010, it has it's own mpi debug cluster and works perferctly with either C code or C++ code. It will help from getting more headaches with mpi.

Comment: Good point. Debugging MPI can be a pain the south.